Parametrization of indecomposable modules via quiver varieties
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $Q$ a quiver without oriented cycles and $m^\alpha (Q)$ the variety of quiver representations with dimension vector $\alpha$. There is a canonical algebraic group $G$ acting on $m^\alpha (Q)$ such that the orbits are in one to one correspondence to $kQ$-modules with dimension vector $\alpha$. I am having trouble understanding the implications of an argument in: V.G. Kac, Infinite Root Systems, Representations of Graphs and Invariant Theory, Inventiones math. 56, 5-92 (1980). It goes as follows (see the end of page 71). The set $m^\alpha_\text{ind} (Q) \subseteq m^\alpha (Q)$ of elements corresponding to indecomposable $kQ$-modules is a constructible $G$-invariant subset. By Rosenlicht's Theorem $m^\alpha_\text{ind} (Q)$ is a finite disjoint union of $G$-invariant sets $X_1, \dots, X_n$ such that each of them admits a geometric quotient $X_i /\sim $. Does this imply the following?

There are finitely many affine varieties $V_1, \dots, V_n$ with coordinate rings $k[V_i]$ and matrices $A_f$ over $k[V_i]$ for each arrow $f$ in $Q$ such that $x\in V_i$ gives rise to a $kQ$-module with matrix $A_f(x)$ at the arrow $f$. In this way we obtain every indecomposable $kQ$-module with dimension vector $\alpha$, up to isomorphism, exactly once.

Presumably $V_i = X_i/\sim$ in the above? For example, let $Q = 1\rightarrow 2 \rightrightarrows 3$. The indecomposable $kQ$-modules with dimension vector $(1,2,2)$ come in families such as
$k \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}} k^2 \xrightarrow[\text{id}]{\begin{pmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}} k^2, \qquad k \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}} k^2 \xrightarrow[\text{id}]{\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 \\
0 & x
\end{pmatrix}} k^2\quad $ and $\quad k \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}} k^2 \xrightarrow[\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 \\
0 & x
\end{pmatrix}]{\text{id}} k^2$.
I am also wondering if we really need quiver varieties. Does something similar work for arbitrary finite dimensional $k$-algebras?
